# E QUERY SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL mongodb

Tags: bash, mongodb

I am running the following query in a bash script, giving the error `E QUERY SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL`

```
mongo $MONGO_DATABASE --eval "printjson(db.mycollection.find({\"created_at\" : { \"$""lte\" : ISODate(2016-04-"$i"T09:26:31.190Z) }}).toArray())"
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot double quote inside ISODate : `ISODate(\"2016-04-"$i"T09:26:31.190Z\")` :

```
mongo $MONGO_DATABASE --eval "printjson(db.mycollection.find({\"created_at\" : { \"$""lte\" : ISODate(\"2016-04-"$i"T09:26:31.190Z\")}}).toArray())"
```